# Automatically wrapping lines in Ask Ubuntu

Tags: support, asking-questions, formatting, markdown, code-formatting

I'm new to forums and stuff like that. I need to post my wifi-info scripts output in Ask Ubuntu using Firefox and I need to keep  it as it is without wrapping any lines. As soon as copy and paste it, it automatically wraps the long lines. Is there any way to not wrap the lines? Thanks.

Comment: no it's actually from the internet browser (yes in Ubuntu but I think it's in general). I need to post my wifi-info scripts output in Ubuntu but i don't know how to do it without wrapping the lines

Comment: Well the question needs more info either way. Please [edit] it. Also you mention forum in the title

Comment: For example? what can I ad?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting .. Paste the data and select it and do ctrl+k. Its markdown syntax

Comment: Right sorry I miss-named it... I edited the title and some of the text specifying what I needed to do

Answer (score 9):

Click the gray circle with a question mark inside it in the upper right corner of the Ask Ubuntu markdown editor to show the link for advanced help (in red letters) which tells all the rules for formatting text in the markdown editor.

[image]

When text that is formatted as a code sample by clicking on **{}** in the markdown editor is too long to fit inside the window, line wrapping is suppressed and the text is formatted as a code sample. The code sample formatted text is appropriate for formatting wifi-info scripts and other scripts generally. A horizontal scrollbar is added automatically underneath the code sample if necessary so that all the text can be read by moving the scrollbar.

Below is an example of what your question looks like when it is formatted as a code sample.

```
I'm new to forums and stuff like that. I need to post my wifi-info scripts output in AskUbuntu using Firefox and I need to keep it as it is without wrapping any lines. As soon as copy and paste it, it automatically wraps the long lines. Is there any way to not wrap the lines? Thanks.
```

Comment: Another useful source for the markdown syntax is https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting.